# How to create a C++ project in Eclipse CDT using existing source files and an existing CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, eclipse

The title says it all: I have source files and a `CMakeLists.txt` for an existing C++ project. Now I want to create a project in Eclipse CDT using those files.

I want to be able to build the project with the "build" button from within Eclipse once I'm done, and I want to be able to use GDB.

I've used the CMake option to create Eclipse projects before, but it didn't always work flawlessly and I was told the CMake generator for Eclipse is supposedly outdated.

I know I could just create an empty project and then copy the source files into it, but what about the `CMakeLists.txt`? I want Eclipse to know how to build the project.

I'm new to Eclipse and there are like fifty ways to start a new project with or without existing source files, so some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using mingw? There are 4 generator choices for Eclipse in CMake. From the shell cmake --help will give you the generator options.

Comment: @drescherjm No, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. Yeah I've used the CMake option to create Eclipse projects before, but it didn't always work flawlessly and I was told the CMake generator for Eclipse is supposedly pretty outdated.

Comment: Probably `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ../build`  from the source folder. Assuming the ../build folder exists.

Comment: ***I was told the CMake generator for Eclipse is supposedly pretty outdated.*** I would not know about that. Sorry. I use CMake daily but not with Eclipse.